# Excel problem: Exported from OBIEE to Excel analysis adding time part to a date column

Tags: excel, oracle, date, time, obiee

There is a date column used in OBIEE analysis. That column is declared as 'date' datatype in Oracle table, type in rpd is also 'DATE'. However, when exported to Excel, Excel is adding time values to the end of date part of this column. Here is a simple analysis:

[image]

The same analysis when exported into Excel:

[image]

As you can see, it is adding '5:00:00' to the end of '11.05.2022'. My guess is it is adding timezone values by default, which is the following in our OBIEE:

[image]

How can we prevent Excel from adding unnecessary values? Should we change settings in instanceconfig.xml file to use formatted value using 'UseFormattedValue' parameter? Or is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UseFormattedValue is the way to go because your problem isn't the Oracle side, but rather Microsoft trying to be "smart" in their interpretation in Excel.
https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/bi12214/biee/BIESG/GUID-FF6954BA-2DE0-4422-BA58-05F32936F4FF.htm#BIESG9196

Comment: Thank you, @Chris, adding UseFormattedValue in instanceconfig.xml solved the problem!

Comment: Hi, is there any way to do the same for CSV export? We tried to add UseFormattedValue for xsi:type formattedText, but it did not help @Chris